# “Abby does not like Cody or Dana”

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, logic-translation

[image]

In [this exercise](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/intrologic/exercises/exercise_01_01.html) in Stanford's Introduction to Logic course, based on the given table, the final sentence "Abby does not like Cody or Dana" is considered false.

Doesn't that sentence mean "Abby doesn't like Code or Abby doesn't like Dana"? For the whole of this sentence to be true, at least one part of the two is true; so, this sentence true, isn't it?

Comment: In English, it means she doesn't like either of them. She doesn't like Cody *and* she doesn't like Dana.

Comment: Doesn't English use "nor" for negative possibilities?

Comment: Not when connecting a list of names, terms, nouns that have been "factored" in this way. 'nor' is subtler still, usually found in the company of 'neither'.  Use of it without 'neither' is, I'd say, "advanced" and you should probably avoid it if you're asking this question:) Note that if Abby truly dislikes the other two, you'd say "Abby dislikes [both] Cody and Dana."

Comment: @BrianO The linked exercise listed both statements "Abby does not like Cody or Dana." (the statement in the question) and "Abby likes Cody or Dana." It seems that the exercise interprets "Abby does not like Cody or Dana." as $\neg$"Abby likes Cody or Dana.", as if the "does not" can be treated as a $\neg$. Is that right?

Comment: @BrianO "Abby does not like Cody or Dana" means "She doesn't like Cody *and* she doesn't like Dana". Does the statement in the question "Abby doesn't like Code or Abby doesn't like Dana" have the same meaning as "Abby doesn't like Code *and* Dana"? Also by the De Morgan's laws?

Comment: I’ll say yes both pairs of sentences mean the same thing, and you’re right to see De Morgan at work. However, note that it’s unusual in English to say "Abby doesn't like Cody and Dana" when you means Abby dislikes at least one of Cody and Dana. Most people aren’t logicians and popular usage with these constructions is careless (or just incorrect) and as a result ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “**Abby does not like Cody or Dana**”

The contrived sentence “A does not like C or D” is ambiguous, as its intended meaning depends on whether ‘not’ or ‘or’ is its ***main connective***, that is, which word is being stressed as the sentence is being read aloud:

1. A does ***not*** like C or D

   It is not that (A likes C or D)

   It is not that (A like C or A likes D)

   (A dislikes C) *and* (A dislikes D)

   Idiomatic phrasing:

   - **Abby likes neither Cody nor Dana**
   - **Abby dislikes (both) Cody and Dana**
2. A does not like C ***or*** D

   (A does not like C) or (A does not like D)

   (A dislikes C) *or* (A dislikes D)

   Idiomatic phrasing:

   - **Abby either dislikes Cody or dislikes Dana**

Answer (score 3):

If I say "I don't eat fish or cheese" that **usually** means that I do not eat fish **and** I do not eat cheese, not that I possibly don't eat fish but I sometimes eat some cheddar, or I never touch cheese but I partake of the occasional mackerel.

So in this case the answer is correct, if she does not like Cody or Dana she doesn't like Cody and she doesn't like Dana.

It seems more of a question about English than about mathematics.

Comment: as this is a logic course, I thought "or" would imply the meaning of the logical "or", hence my confusion.

Comment: I don't know anything about you but this kind of confusion is common with non-native speakers of English. At least you learnt something useful, didn't you? Good luck with the logic course.

Answer (score 0):

The instructor wants us to deem each relational table as depicting a possible world. Each possible world comprises some conditions. The sentences are utterances about a possible world.

In the given table (possible world), at least one of the conditions, *likes*(Abby, Cody) and *likes*(Abby, Dana), holds; we may not know which. But the given sentence expresses a denial of this, so to say, the compound condition --which may be formulated as *not*-*likes*(Abby, Cody *or* Dana).